# Mapping over a nested column and computing t-tests between two groups

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some data which looks like:

```
# Groups:   date [4]
  date       data             
  <date>     <list>           
1 2021-01-31 <tibble [10 × 3]>
2 2021-02-07 <tibble [10 × 3]>
3 2021-02-14 <tibble [10 × 3]>
4 2021-02-15 <tibble [10 × 3]>
```

Inside each nested `data`, the data looks like:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 3
      id     y     x
   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
 1     4   109     5
 2     6   116     1
 3    19   357     5
 4    22   170     5
 5    31   122     5
 6    33    23     1
 7    36    39     1
 8    38    96     5
 9    39   112     1
10    41   172     5
```

I would like to map over these 4 tibbles and compute t-tests between the groups in column `x`. so for group 1 and 5. The data I want to compare is in column `y`.

I am trying to do it in a tidy approach.

I can do it for a single tibble:

```
grp1 = data$data[[1]] %>% 
  filter(x == 1) %>% 
  pull(y)

grp2 = data$data[[1]] %>% 
  filter(x == 5) %>% 
  pull(y)

t.test(grp1, grp2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `map` to iterate over each data and perform `t.test` on it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %> mutate(t_test = map(data, ~t.test(y~x, .x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R`

```
df$t_test <- lapply(df$data, \(x) t.test(y ~ x, data = x))
```